# How to create a folder when user specify the number to be created in unix?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, functional-programming

How can I create a Folder when I prompt a user to enter how many folders he wants to create in unix?Lets say for example the user input 5 it should create a Five folder name folder1, folder2 ,folder3, folder4 ,folder5. How can i do this in unix?

Comment: Have you tried using a for loop?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried the while loop. But the requirement is to use the for loop. Can you please provide the code?Im new to unix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supose you will do this with a bash script. In that case you can use a loop and the `mkdir` command. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "How many folders?" num_folder

for (( i = 1; i <= num_folder; i++ )); do
        mkdir folder$i
done
```

this will create 4 folders with the names `folder1`, `folder2`, `folder3` and `folder4`.

Comment: thanks.But can you please give the complete code.I tried assigning variable for the input value of user but it seems im doing wrong.Sorry but im new to unix.Can you please help me with this.

Comment: the only difference is that now  it asks the user how many folders it wants to create using the `read` command. This will not override folders and fails if there is one with the same name as the one it wants to create:)

Comment: Yeah I already done that and its working by the way. Thank you so much, but can you please give a code using for loop because I need to use the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the user how many he wants this way :

```
read -p "How many folders do you want to create ? : " numberoffolder
```

Then use the var `$numberoffolder` to loop & name folders